# live search in dropdown using ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

how can i use this code for ajax live search, for select option?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$j(document).ready(function() {
    $j('#keyword').on('input', function() {
        var searchKeyword = $(this).val();
        if (searchKeyword.length >= 0) {
            $.post('search.php', { keywords: searchKeyword }, function(data) {
                $j('ul#content').empty()
                $.each(data, function() {
                    $j('ul#content').append('*<a href="reserve.php' + this.id + '">' + this.title + '</a>');
                });
            }, "json");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

this code works correctly with input type['text'] like:

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="keyword" />
```

but i want it work with :

```
<select name="field" id="keyword">
<option value="1">sometext</option>
<option value="2">sometext</option>
<option value="3">sometext</option>
<option value="4">sometext</option>
</select>
```

how can i get the value of the selected options using above code?

Comment: Is the issue that the event isn't firing or that you aren't getting the results you want?

Comment: i think i can not get the value of the selected option to post on php file.

Comment: Are you wanting your value to be `1, 2, 3, or 4` or `sometext`?

Comment: these are 1,2,3,4 in database. and i needs this values.

Comment: So if you do `console.log(searchKeyword)` after you define `searchKeyword` what is your console showing?

Comment: i don't understand what you say. but i know changing this part of the code for selected option will be enough.
     $j('#keyword').on('input', function() {
     var searchKeyword = $(this).val();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$j(document).ready(function() {
$j('#keyword').on('change', function() {
    var searchKeyword = $("#keyword option:selected").val();;
    if (searchKeyword.length >= 0) {
        $.post('search.php', { keywords: searchKeyword }, function(data) {
            $j('ul#content').empty()
            $.each(data, function() {
                $j('ul#content').append('*<a href="reserve.php' + this.id + '">' + this.title + '</a>');
            });
        }, "json");
    }
});
});
</script>
```